# Difference between render and view keyword in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, view, render

When would you use `{{render "viewGoesHere" content}}` vs  `{{view App.viewGoesHereView contentBinding="this"}}`?

I'm trying to dynamically change the template to be rendered when different links in a side-bar menu are clicked. But the above two methods change to the correct template only when a link(from side-bar) is clicked the first time. Any links clicked after that produced the same template as the one generated the first time.

tl;dr: my templates are not dynamically changing when different link in the side-bar are clicked.

Here is my view:

```
App.ViewGoesHereView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: function(){
        var templateName = 'baseTemplate';

        var value = this.get('controller.model.Name');

        if (Ember.compare(value, 'abc') === 0) {
            templateName = 'abcTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        else if (Ember.compare(value, 'xyz') === 0) {
            templateName = 'xyzTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        return templateName;

    }.property('controller.model.Name'),

});
```

I'm basically getting the correct template based off the Name in the current model, and I can get the correct name in the templateName variable, but it doesn't render.

Comment: @SamSelikoff <div>{{view App.ContentItemView contentBinding="this"}}</div> I put my working code below. But I can't understand the computed property isn't updating the value variable dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample you are trying to connect `templateName` property to `controller.model.Name` this approach works for the first time as you also said but `templateName` property is used by the ember view for first time only. i.e. if `templateName` changes after the view is rendered it does not re-render the view. And if you want your approach to work you will need to re-render the view each time your dependent properties changes.

```
//sample
App.ViewGoesHereView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: function(){
        var templateName = 'baseTemplate';

        var value = this.get('controller.model.Name');

        if (Ember.compare(value, 'abc') === 0) {
            templateName = 'abcTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        else if (Ember.compare(value, 'xyz') === 0) {
            templateName = 'xyzTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        return templateName;

    }.property('controller.model.Name'),
    //new property to re-render the view
    reRenderView: function () {
        this.rerender();
    }.observes('controller.model.Name')

});
```

**NOTE:** I haven't tested this code since I didn't had the full use case of your scenario. Please do revert back if this dosen't works.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `value ('controller.model.Name')` was't being updated every time a new link from the side-bar was clicked. So I inserted a jquery function to get the updated name on every click, and assign that to value variable.

```
App.ViewGoesHereView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: function(){
        var templateName = 'baseTemplate';

        var val = this.get('controller.model.Name');
        var value;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('li').click(function () {
                val = ($(this).text());
            });
        });

        value = val;

        if (Ember.compare(value, 'abc') === 0) {
            templateName = 'abcTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        else if (Ember.compare(value, 'xyz') === 0) {
            templateName = 'xyzTemplate';
            return templateName;
        }

        return templateName;

    }.property('controller.model.Name'),

});
```